# Логирование "медленных запросов" в apache и nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

Возможно ли в какой-нибудь лог apache или nginx записывать запросы пользователей (домен+REQUEST_URI), по которым ответ сервера занимает, к примеру, более 3-х секунд?

Поясню: Пользователь в браузере набирает

```
site.ru/takoi-to-uri
```

Запрос через nginx попадает в apache. Apache запускает php-скрипты на выполнение, с кучами include-ов. После завершения выполнения всех скриптов (т.е. формирования ответа сервером) apache возвращает ответ пользователю.

Так вот, нужно записывать все запросы (site.ru/takoi-to-uri), по которым сервер трудился более 3-х секунд.

Это возможно сделать для apache/nginx?

На сервере куча сайтов и куча php-скриптов. Поэтому на уровне php логировать проблематично. Задача - отследить "не эффективно" работающие сайты и php-скрипты в них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изобретение подобного условия для nginx выглядит немного сложным для реализации. По этому правильным подходом будет [записывать в лог](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) значение переменной [$upstream_response_time](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_response_time) и последующий анализ лога простейшим скриптом.

```
log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
    '[request_time=$request_time, upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time, cache=$upstream_cache_status] (upstream $upstream_addr // $upstream_status)" '
    '[$host] [$server_protocol]';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.ru.access.log main;
```

Конфигурация логирования nginx даёт нам возможность задать условие при выполнении которого запись добавится в лог:

> access_log путь [формат [buffer=размер] [gzip[=степень]] [flush=время]
>   **[if=условие]**];

Так что если хочется совсем уж странного то можно поступить так:

```
# я не пробовал, но должно сработать
http {
    map $upstream_response_time $loggable {
        ~^[3456789]\.[0-9]+  1;
        ~^[1-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+ 1;
        default 0; 
    }

    server {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/site.ru.access.log combined if=$loggable;
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает, если убрать server {}.

Comment: примите ответ, если подошло