# Отклонять запросы ко всем сайтам на сервере по UserAgent

Tags: apache, nginx

Ubuntu 16.04.  Множество сайтов работают по связке nginx+apache.
Остро встает проблема борьбы с ботами всяческих сервисов типа MegaIndex, MJ12bot и т.д.

Необходимо отклонять запросы ко всем сайтам на уровне nginx или apache, если userAgent пользователя частично совпадает со списком "запрещенных". Это можно реализовать?

Сейчас для борьбы с ботами в файлы .htaccess в корнях каждого сайта добавляю строки:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot|ia_archiver|LinkpadBot|MegaIndex|AhrefsBot|SemrushBot|opensiteexplorer
RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
```

Возможно ли как-то "централизовано" бороться с ботами, прописать одно правильно для всех сайтов на сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Для nginx:

```
http {
    map $http_user_agent $bad_client {
      default                 0;
      "~*^MJ12bot"            1;
    }

    server {
        if ($bad_client) {
            return 403;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: это где надо прописать и как обозначить несколько сравнений для userAgent?

Comment: в map, по строке на каждого агента

Comment: Сделал, перезагрузил nginx. Ограничение НЕ работает (использую ту же строку, что и ранее в .htaccess). Возможно блок server {..} не работает? такая же ситуация была тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1035032/Логирование-медленных-запросов-в-apache-и-nginx . Там я убрал блок server {} и заработало. В этом же случае как поступить не знаю.

Comment: Перепроверил: секция map {...} - работает. Секция server {...} - игнорируется. Может быть ее нужно в другое место переместить или по-другому переписать?

Comment: если же содержимое блока server {...} прописать в конфиге для конкретного сайта /home/admin/web/site.ru.nginx.conf - то ограничение работает. Но как сделать разом для всех сайтов???

Comment: никак. подключение можно упростить перенеся проверку условия в инклюд

Comment: т.е. для каждого сайта нужно прописывать содержимое блока server?

Comment: вы хотите чтобы я ответил на ваш вопрос не зная как у вас что-то там из "множества сайтов" сконфигурировано?

Answer (score 0):

На шаред это делать легко - не знаю, как у Вас организовано на сервере, корень "корня" - то есть, выше уровня папки нахождения всех доменов, где находятся соответствующие файлы и внесение изменений в них касаются всех папок/доменов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделал также (на уровень выше всех сайтов файл .htaccess), теперь ошибка 500.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать все из файла и пустой поставьте - посмотрите, что будет.

Comment: если в самом верхнем .htacces пусто, то все сайты работают нормально (как раньше)

Comment: Тогда дело не в файле, а в инструкциях - поэкспериментируйте, попробуйте добавлять блоки классически - с обертками по проверке модулей и прочим - например, поробуйте просто поставить в бан какой-то ip - в обертке соответтвующего блока.

Comment: сделал Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.123.123.123  - сразу ошибка 500

Comment: Обертку вставляли?: <Limit HEAD GET POST>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 127.0.0.0
</Limit> и попробуйте убрать все и добавить сверху только DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 default - если будет выбивать, то пробуйте через nginx и смотрите настройки сервера - как там все организовано и откуда "ноги растут" - тогда без методов тыка можно что думать.

Comment: Сделал так, не знаю на сколько правильно и безопасно, но работает: 
1) в apache2.conf прописываем :
<Directory /home/admin/web/>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

2) в /home/admin/web/.htaccess прописываем :
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot|ia_archiver|LinkpadBot|MegaIndex|AhrefsBot|SemrushBot|opensiteexplorer
RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]

Comment: Ну и отлично! - что неправильного - это нормально. Ну, впрочем, может кто еще какое мнение выскажет.